# How to read in n columns of CSV fie to check they are null?

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, variables, csv

I'm trying read in a spreadsheet that has this format

```
username,   lastname,   firstname,    x1,      x2,       x3,      x4
user1,       dudette,    mary,         7,       2,                 4
user2,       dude,       john,         6,       2,        4,
user3,       dudest,     rad,
user4,       dudaa,      pad,          3,       3,        5,       9
```

basically, it has usernames, the names those usernames correspond to, and values for each x. What I want to do is read in this from a csv file and then find all of the blank spaces and fill them in with 5s. My approach to doing this was to read in the whole array and then substitute all null spaces with 0s. This is the code so far...

The solution I got, thanks to another respondent on stackoverflow, was

```
n=5
while IFS=, read username lastname firstname x1 x2 x3 x4; do
    ! [[ $x1 ]] && x1=$n
    ! [[ $x2 ]] && x2=$n
    ! [[ $x3 ]] && x3=$n
    ! [[ $x4 ]] && x4=$n
    echo $username,$lastname,$firstname,$x1,$x2,$x3,$x4
done < something.csv > newfile.csv && mv newfile.csv something.csv
```

For the last several hours, I have been now trying to figure out how I can expand this to an n column case. So in the example above, I know that I have 7 columns and so I have seven variables I read in. What I'm trying to do now is figure out how to expand that to the n column case. In the even that another column is added, I still need the code to work.

Comment: `IFS=, read username lastname firstname x1 x2 x3 x4; ` : change it to `IFS=, read -a columns; ` & then parse the array called `columns`

Answer (score 1):

awk is better suited for this type of csv parsing and formatting.

```
awk -F '[, ]+' -v n=7 '{for (i=1; i<=n; i++) printf "%10s%s", $i, (i<n)?OFS:RS}' OFS=, x
  username,  lastname, firstname,        x1,        x2,        x3,        x4
     user1,   dudette,      mary,         7,         2,         4,          
     user2,      dude,      john,         6,         2,         4,          
     user3,    dudest,       rad,          ,          ,          ,          
     user4,     dudaa,       pad,         3,         3,         5,         9
```

Comment: +1: If you do `"%-10s%s"` then it would format a lot better. **Update** It would probably leave trailing space though.

Comment: Yes I delayed my answer for 5+ minutes playing with different printf formats and finally resigned myself to this one.

Comment: `:)` I am liking this `printf "%-s%s ", $i, (i<n)?OFS:RS}' OFS=',' csv | column -t` though it calls for an extra pipe!

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Anubhava should be faster (since it's awk, not bash). I am adding an answer just to answer your question about how to extend `read` to n columns.

```
n=5
while IFS=, read -a columns; do
    for i in ${!columns[@]}; do # * NOTE1
        [ "${columns[$i]}" ] || columns[$i]=$n
    done
    printf "%s" ${columns[0]}; printf ",%s" ${columns[@]:1} # * NOTE2
done < something.csv > newfile.csv && mv newfile.csv something.csv
```

**NOTE1:** If the entries are blank, but placeholders are present, use the for loop as is.
If the number of columns in the csv file is not fixed (e.g. check user3 row), then change the inner for loop to `for ((i=0;i<$max_columns;i++)); do`

**NOTE2:** In the printf commands, change `%s` to `%10s` if desired.